# Send partial list with errors in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo

With a query that returns a list:

```
{
  users(first: 10) {
    messages(first: 10) {
      foo
    }
  }
}
```

and a resolver for messages -

```
const errors = [];

async function messagesResolver(user, {first}, ctx, info) {
  const messages = await Promise.all(
    user.messages.map(
      messageId => fetch(messageId).catch(e => {
        // Collect error
        errors.push(err);

        // Ignore this failed message id
        return null;
      })
    )
  );

  // TODO:
  // How do I add errors to the list of errors
  // sent to the client

  return messages.filter(m => m != null);
}
```

Is it possible to return only a Partial List of messages whose fetch succeeded? Is it possible send the errors along and let the client decide how to handle the errors?

Replacing message with an Error does this to an extent, but with `null` values in the resolved list -

```
messages = [ { 1 }, { 2 }, new Error(3), { 4 }, new Error(5) ]
```

resolves to

```
data = [ { 1 }, { 2 }, null, { 4 }, null ]
errors = [ Error(3), Error(5) ]
```

But, is it possible to send the errors via another API (say, `info.addError(new Error(3))` to achieve the following result?

```
data = [ { 1 }, { 2 }, { 4 } ]
errors = [ Error(3), Error(5) ]
```